# How to keep the keeping JS changes on DOM after refresh?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, page-refresh

I am designing a system that allows entry to a particular store as well as exit from it and it counts the people inside the store.

I use JAVASCRIPT to hide the "Entrance" option list as soon as it is changed and then the Exit button is displayed.

So If I refresh the page the before clicking "exit" the exit button is hidden again and the entrance is shown so the person that "entered" the store needs to enter again in order to check out.

How can I save the status of the exit button shown after refreshing the browser?

HTML markup:

```
<form>
    <select id="f1" name="id" onchange="loadDocs(this.value)">
        <option value="">:</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="check"><b style="font-family:Baumans;font-size:24px;">. . .</b></div>

<button id="b1" type="button" onclick="loadDoca()">check out</button>
```

jQuery funcs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#b1").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#f1").show();
    
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#f1").change(function(){
    alert("now your in!, please don't forget to check out as well!");
    $(this).hide();
    $("#b1").show();
    
  });
});
```

Javascript for updating database:

```
function loadDocs(str) {
  if(str==" "){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " ";
    return;
    }
    else{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
 
  xhttp.open("GET", "Client-check-in.php?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
  }
}
function loadDoca() {
  
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("checkO").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
 
  xhttp.open("GET", "Client-check-out.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Can you share us a piece of code ?, because i don't think i'm getting it yet

Comment: posted code ,i will try explain the problem the best as i can: when i choose option the user ""enters" the shop with selected id , but if he will refresh or go to another page he only could enter again and then exit

Comment: Please post actual code, not images of it. It's better for people to retrieve your problem later on and to debug it for people willing to help you.

Comment: thx im new just now figured out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem('status', true);
```

Or the [sessionstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

```
sessionStorage.setItem('status', false);
```

In [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/localstorage-vs-sessionstorage-c22164aff067) you have a nice explanation about local and session storage.

Comment: didnt really understand how or where to use it ,i understand the local storage idea ,what i actually need is that the "exit button" will shown until i press it even when i refresh the page